# Understanding Big O notation - discrete math?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have questions with the solutions below but I'm still having trouble understanding how to solve these problems?

Like for a) I don't understand how 17$n^2$  + 4 got turned into 17$n^2$  + 4$n^2$. I also don't know what happened to the -3 for the first part of the inequality?

I'd really appreciate it if someone could walk me through the general solution of how to solve these types of questions.

[image]

Additionally, I was also wondering what difference would it make if the O was a Ω symbol instead? I've seen similar questions in my textbook like 4$n^2$  + 3log + 7$n^3$ is Ω($n^3$) and was wondering what difference would this make in the solution?

Comment: because $4n-3\le4n\le 4n^2$ for $n\ge1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are working a Big-O bound, you are free to replace a term by anything larger. E.g. in $$-3+17n^2+4n$$ they replaced $-3$ by $0$ and $4n$ by $4n^2$ to get a simpler expression.

(Note that every term could have been replaced by $175n^4$ as well, giving an $O(n^4)$ bound, but this is less tight. Also note that the replacement need not be larger for all $n$, only as of some $n_0$.)

For an $\Omega$ bound, you are free to replace a term by a smaller one.

Answer (score 0):

For a), it's not mysterious: the aim is to find a constant $C>0$  such that $\;|17n^2+4n-3|<Cn^2$ for all $n$ large enough.

First, observe the roots of $17n^2+4n-3$ are between $-1$ and $1$, so this quadratic will be positive if $n\ge 1$. So:

1. $0<17n^2+4n-3<17n^2+4n$.
2. Since $n\ge 1$, we have $4n \le 4n^2$, whence $0<17n^2+4n-3 < 21n^2$.

Thus  a constant $C$ such that the required inequality is satisfied has been found: it is $C=21$. 
Of course this is not the only possible constant. Any $C>21$ will also work.

A smaller constant can be found: as $4n\le n^2$ if $n\ge4$,  we have $\;17n^2+4n-3<18n^2\;$ for such $n$s.